# Scala extended constructor

Tags: class, scala, constructor, arguments

Say I have:

```
class DecisionTree(private val instances: Array[Instance]){
```

and I want to calculate another instance variable, say `totalEntropy`, that requires me to do some further processing that will require instantiating a hashmap as part of the calculations.

I've come up with:

```
private var totalEntropy = (() => {
  val m = collection.mutable.Map()
  ...
})()
```

but this seems awkward.  Should I just forgo the arguments in the class definition altogether and use an auxiliary constructor?  What is a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
private var totalEntropy = {
  val m = collection.mutable.Map()
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, for some reason I assumed `{}` were used to instantiate a special type of data structure.